# iOS App icon and Splash screen aren't updating for PhoneGap Project

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using PhoneGap 3.4.0 to create an app.

Within my Phonegap project I have added my own custom app icons here:

```
MyProject/www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png
MyProject/www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png
MyProject/www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png
MyProject/www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png
```

And I have added my own custom Splashscreens here:

```
MyProject/www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png
MyProject/www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png
MyProject/www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png
MyProject/www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png
MyProject/www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-2x.png
MyProject/www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape.png
MyProject/www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png
MyProject/www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png
MyProject/www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png
```

I then run this via command line in the `MyProject` folder:

```
phonegap build ios
```

The app seems to compile correctly and I can open the app in xCode and run it in the iPhone simulator, the problem is that the simulator still shows the Cordova default app icon and splashscreen.

I have also replaced the files in the below directress before and after running `phonegap build ios` but that doesn't seem to fix it either either.

```
MyProject/platforms/ios/My Project/Resources/icons/
MyProject/platforms/ios/My Project/Resources/splash/
MyProject/platforms/ios/www/res/icon/ios/
MyProject/platforms/ios/www/res/screen/ios/
```

I've read over the [documantation for Icons and Splash Screens](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens) but can't seem to figure out why it's not working for me.

Am I missing a step? Should I be running a different command?

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830467/generating-ios-and-android-icons-in-cordova-phonegap/23917490#23917490

Comment: I've tried the solutions offered from those answers and none of them have worked for me.

Comment: Also, notice in my question above that I already tried the solution that you provided. Thanks.

Comment: In xcode, go to the screen where you can view the list of icon and splashscreen resources then click on each one and reselect the asset. I have had to do this on a number of occasions, it seems that xcode caches the assets if the name doesn't change. After you re-select each asset, try rebuilding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I was doing everything correctly, however in **Xcode**, I needed to go to:

```
Product > Clean
```

...to clear out any old settings and cache.

I found this answer here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/18868704/647621